# Correct usage of phonegap v3.0 config.xml without phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova, app-config, cordova-3

I encountered a lot of differences with the new PhoneGap v3.0.

Normal API features included in the config.xml do not work anymore eg.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
```

PhoneGaps own online documentation do not offer another way for this, atleast i can find it if there are some.

I tried to include things like:

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</feature>
```

If i run PhoneGap v2.9.0 everything works fine.

What is the correct usage, i cant find anything that works ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I found some more material online.  People say that its not yet supportet by phonegap build.  I am however not sure if thats true.

Comment: Source: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/adding_plugins_to_a_phonegap_3_0_remote_build

Comment: can anyone confirm this?